# REST API call works at Postman but not at Jenkins

Tags: api, rest, jenkins, runtime-error

I'm facing a problem that seems to be simple. I'm trying to call a REST API from Jenkins build step and it's not working.
I make this call from postman and it works just fine, but from Jenkins, it doesn't. Bellow are some pictures of my configurations.

**Postman Settings**

As you can see on this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dU79vjzi2OG67IBOI-Jv52hOgon4_7aB/view?usp=sharing), at postman my request works perfectly.

**Jenkins Settings**

At this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iz-q4WdSExSLViGGV3JtCWW0tGW3p5NE/view?usp=sharing) you can see that I'm using the same settings at Jenkins, although it doesn't work.

Finally, the error message that is presented when I try to run the Jenkins.

```
Started by user Hugo da Silva da Silva
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Power BI - Atualizador mensal
HttpMethod: POST
URL: https://login.windows.net/7348b8c4-3705-4965-b18a-c02e2d5a28eb/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
Accept: application/json
Sending request to url: https://login.windows.net/7348b8c4-3705-4965-b18a-c02e2d5a28eb/oauth2/token
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
hudson.AbortException: Fail: the returned code 400 is not in the accepted range: [[100‥399]]
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.responseCodeIsValid(HttpRequestExecution.java:369)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.processResponse(HttpRequestExecution.java:379)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.authAndRequest(HttpRequestExecution.java:295)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:226)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:229)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:79)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequest.perform(HttpRequest.java:398)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1856)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'HTTP Request' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anybody has ever faced a similar situation? Any tip?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Posting here the solution given by my friend @brunolmfg.

The problem was the body content format. I was posting it using json format, whereas I shoud post it as url encoded. Here is the body content that worked:

```html
grant_type=client_credentials&resouce=XXX&client_id=YYY&client_secret=ZZZZ
```